# Drawing an arc between two 3D points

Tags: tikz

I am trying to draw composite 3D shapes, and I am struggling drawing arcs between two 3D points. In the example below I would like to draw a dashed arc of 180 degrees between from D to H clockwise, and a solid arc of 180 degrees from D to H anti-clockwise. However, when I try

```
\draw (D)  arc[radius=\R, start angle=180, end angle=0];
```

I don't get the arc I want. Below is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{-43}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1,
    tdplot_main_coords]
    \def\R{2}
    \def\h{6}
    \coordinate (A) at ({\R*cos(0)},{\R*sin(0)},0);
    \coordinate (B) at ({\R*cos(45)},{\R*sin(45)},0);
    \coordinate (C) at ({\R*cos(90)},{\R*sin(90)},0);    
    \coordinate (D) at ({\R*cos(135)},{\R*sin(135)},0);
    \coordinate (E) at ({\R*cos(180)},{\R*sin(180)},0);
    \coordinate (F) at ({\R*cos(225)},{\R*sin(225)},0);
    \coordinate (G) at ({\R*cos(270)},{\R*sin(270)},0);
    \coordinate (H) at ({\R*cos(315)},{\R*sin(315)},0);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (O') at (0,0,\h);
    \coordinate (O'') at (0,0,-\h);
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C}{
        \draw[dashed] (\i) -- (O');
    \node at (\i) [above]{$\i$};}
    \foreach \i in {D,E,F,G,H}{
        \draw (\i) -- (O');
    \node at (\i) [below]{$\i$};}   
    \draw[red] (O) circle (\R);
    \draw[red] (D) -- (O'') -- (H);
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- (H);
    \node at (O') [above]{$O'$};
    \node at (O'') [below,thick,red]{$O''$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Composite shape.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered or commented, I came up with my own solution, which is using a two-coordinate system instead of three, but it works...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \def\xRadius{2}
    \def\yRadius{0.4*\xRadius}
    \def\h{5.4}
    \coordinate (A) at ({\xRadius*cos(45)},{\yRadius*sin(45)});
    \coordinate (B) at ({\xRadius*cos(90)},{\yRadius*sin(90)});    
    \coordinate (C) at ({\xRadius*cos(135)},{\yRadius*sin(135)});
    \coordinate (D) at ({\xRadius*cos(180)},{\yRadius*sin(180)});
    \coordinate (E) at ({\xRadius*cos(225)},{\yRadius*sin(225)});
    \coordinate (F) at ({\xRadius*cos(270)},{\yRadius*sin(270)});
    \coordinate (G) at ({\xRadius*cos(315)},{\yRadius*sin(315)});
    \coordinate (H) at ({\xRadius*cos(0)},{\yRadius*sin(0)});
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (O') at (0,\h);
    \coordinate (O'') at (0,-\h);
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C}{
        \draw[dashed] (\i) -- (O');
    \node at (\i) [above]{$\i$};}
    \foreach \i in {D,E,F,G,H}{
        \draw (\i) -- (O');
    \node at (\i) [below]{$\i$};}   
    \draw[red,dashed] (H) arc [x radius = \xRadius, y radius = \yRadius, start angle=0, end angle=180];
    \draw[red] (H) arc [x radius = \xRadius, y radius = \yRadius, start angle=0, end angle=-180];
    \draw[red] (D) -- (O'') -- (H);
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- (H);
    \node at (O') [above]{$O'$};
    \node at (O'') [below,thick,red]{$O''$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is a tikz pgf Stack Exachange page. I would guess you would have received a fair number of responses.